# Android Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I am very confused about how to change from `ActionBar` to `toolbar` in my application. I see a lot of documentation, and I cannot find any solution for my problem. Any help with my code is welcome. I need to change all my `actionbar` (deprecated) for the new toolbar and I cannot set the toolbar in the class that I have. A clue to the problem is in my extends or implements. i don't know, thanks for the advice!

```
public class Quizz_View extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private DrawerLayout leftDrawer;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private ActionBar ldActionBar;
    private Toolbar toolBar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle abDrawerToggle;
 // private ArrayList<Class_Questions> questionsList = new
 // ArrayList<Class_Questions>();

    GridView gridView;
    float xInicial;
    float yInicial;
    float xActual;
    float yActual;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);       

      //menu del toolbar
      //toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.MENU);

      //toolbar.setTitle("AD NORMA");
      //toolbar.setSubtitle("INGENIAT");

        Button reply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.replyBtn);
        reply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        final Button finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishBtn);
        finish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        finish.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        /********************/
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        // crea_menu_navegacion();

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        // drawerListView.setAdapter();
        leftDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        abDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, leftDrawer, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        leftDrawer.setDrawerListener(abDrawerToggle);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        leftDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,    GravityCompat.START);
        // drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        /***********************/

        // Inicialización
        ArrayList<Integer> inte = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // ArrayList<Integer> pageNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        actionBar = getActionBar();

        try {

            // ENTRA A PAGINAS
            JSONObject jsonQuiz = new JSONObject(stringQuiz);
            jsonPaginas = jsonQuiz.getString("Paginas");
            JSONArray jsn = new JSONArray(jsonPaginas);
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),    jsonPaginas);

            for (Integer i = 0; i < jsn.length(); i++) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Página " + (i + 1)).setTabListener(this));         
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if (position >= 5)
                    finish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    finish.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    private ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

AND THE XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout /android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbarr"
    layout="@layout/toolbarex"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="28sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:textSize="28sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="28sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="28sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/replyBtn"
    style="@style/buttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Responder" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/finishBtn"
    style="@style/buttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:text="Terminar" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

Comment: you need ActionBarActivity not FragmentActivity

Comment: but i need the functions of fragment activity what can i do?

Comment: It has all the same functions

Comment: thanks for your answers you know this?, this activity already has an actionbar supplied by the window decor

Comment: Search the error and you will find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add toolbar in layout:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
        android:layout_width=”match_parent”
        android:minHeight=”@dimen/triple_height_toolbar”
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Change the following in styles.xml to remove action bar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>
```

in MainActivity.java

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool1);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("ToolBar Demo");
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the Toolbar Xml code before the Viewpager. The ViewPager may be taking the whole screen height and toolbar is getting behind it.

Just place the below code before viewpager instead of afterwards.

```
<include 
 android:id="@+id/toolbarr" layout="@layout/toolbarex"    
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Kindly elaborate your Answer

Comment: Just place the below code before viewpager instead of afterwards.<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbarr"
    layout="@layout/toolbarex"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Answer (score 0):

One clarification: With the new version of the support library, you should be using AppCompatActivity

Step 1: Use a NoActionBar parent theme.

`<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Step 2: Derive your activity from AppCompatActivity.

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Step 3: Add a Toolbar into your hierarchy.

`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>`

Step 4: Attach the Toolbar to your AppCompatActivity.

In MainActivity:
`Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

You can now use getSupportActionBar() to use your toolbar like an ActionBar if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is the code for it.

**Build.Gradle** file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Create a new layout file **toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ahotbrew.toolbar.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/hello_brew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

This is how you create a toolbar. 
The example is from http://www.ahotbrew.com/android-toolbar-example/

If you need to show the toolbar at the bottom then you'll find the code snippet in the link.